# VSCode keybinding to navigate to render method

Tags: reactjs, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

so I am using VSCode for react development and I was wondering if I could jump to the render function with a shortcut. Naturally there is no preconfigured way. So I looked into it and found a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/2246).

```
{
    "key": "shift+alt+p",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen",
    "args": "@:render"
},
```

Problem is, that the shortcut opens up the vscode window. Which is prefilled and I have to press the enter button to do the actual "navigate to". Does anyone know how to do this without pushing enter?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to use a macro to run both the `quickOpen` command and selecting with one keystroke.

Using a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), put this into your settings:

```
  "multiCommand.commands": [

    {
      "command": "multiCommand.goToRender",
      "sequence": [
        {
          "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen",
          "args": "@:render"
        },
        "workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and some keybinding to trigger that macro (in your keybindings.json):

```
{
    "key": "shift+alt+p",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { "command": "multiCommand.goToRender" },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Of course, if you have multiple `render` objects the first will be selected and navigated to.

---

An alternative is to use the [selectBy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) extension which you could configure to jump to the next or previous occurrence of the word `render`.  The extension can move to occurrences of words (and not select anything).  In your settings:

```
 "selectby.regexes": {    

    "goToRender": {
      "moveby": "render",
    }
  }
```

And some keybindings (whatever bindings you want):

```
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+p",          // go up to the previous `render` 
    "when": "editorTextFocus", 
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": ["goToRender", "moveby", "prev", "start"]
  },

  {
    "key": "alt+p",            // go to the next `render`
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": ["goToRender", "moveby", "next", "start"]
  },
```